# Laravel custom validation not working as intended

Tags: php, laravel, alpine.js

So I've been having a problem in my custom validation. It only works to the Commodity Dropdown but in other textboxes, there is no error message. By the way, I am using alpinejs to add more rows.

## input-components.blade.php:

```
<div x-data="eLinkageAddRow()">
    <template x-for="(row,index) in rows" :key="row.id">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
                <label for="associationName" class="form-label label-style">Association Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="associationName[]" id="associationName" autocomplete="off"
                    value="{{ $associationProfile->association }}" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
                <label for="commodity" class="form-label label-style">Commodity</label>
                <select id="commodity" name="commodity[]" class="form-select">
                    <option selected disabled>Select Commodity</option>
                    @foreach ($commodityValues as $id => $value)
                        <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                @error('commodity')
                    <span class="fs-6 text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 mb-2">
                <label for="Variety" class="form-label label-style">Variety</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="variety[]" id="variety" autocomplete="off">
                @error('variety')
                    <span class="fs-6 text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 mb-2">
                <label for="end_Date" class="form-label label-style">Volume (Kg)</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="volume[]" id="volume" autocomplete="off">
                @error('volume')
                    <span class="fs-6 text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                @enderror
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
                    <label for="startDate" class="form-label label-style">Estimated
                        Time of Harvest <br> (Start Date)</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="startDate[]" id="startDate">
                    @error('startDate')
                        <span class="fs-6 text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
                    <label for="endDate" class="form-label label-style">Estimated
                        Time of Harvest <br> (End Date)</label>
                    <input type="Date" class="form-control" name="endDate[]" id="endDate">
                    @error('endDate')
                        <span class="fs-6 text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
            <div x-show="index > 0">
                <div class="col-md-2 mb-2 d-flex mt-auto">
                    <button x-on:click="removeRow(index)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </template>

    <div class="col-md-1 mb-2 d-flex mt-auto">
        <button x-on:click="addRow()" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add more</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

## StoreELinkageRequest.php:

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'commodity' => 'required',
            'variety' => 'required',
            'volume' => 'required',
            'startDate' => 'required|date',
            'endDate' => 'required|date',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'commodity' => 'Please select a commodity.',
            'variety' => 'Please enter the variety.',
            'volume' => 'Please enter the volume.',
            'startDate' => 'Please select the start date.',
            'endDate' => 'Please select the end date.',
        ];
    }
```

## ELinkageController.php

```
public function store(StoreELinkageRequest $request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        foreach ($request->input('associationName') as $key => $associationName) {
            $data = [
                'association' => $associationName,
                'commodity' => $request->input('commodity')[$key],
                'variety' => $request->input('variety')[$key],
                'volume' => $request->input('volume')[$key],
                'startDate' => $request->input('startDate')[$key],
                'endDate' => $request->input('endDate')[$key],
                'userId' => $user->id,
            ];
            ELinkage::create($data);
        }
        return redirect()->route('e-linkage')->with('success', 'Data saved successfully!');
    }
```

I tried removing the commodity dropdown to see if it will work for the other inputs but the error message is still not showing. It only shows an error for the dropdown.

Comment: What does your request payload look like, when you submit for validation?

Comment: I would go through all of the form elements - some of your IDs do not match, some of them have case insensitivities - e.g. your label for volume says its for `end_Date` - if you check through for any inconsistencies it might help you out - worst case scenario, it doesn't help but your code is tidier and more readable!

Comment: @party-ring Thank you for pointing out some inconsistencies in my form elements.

Comment: @Repox                                                                                                              _token: odwlyoSlMdpAdAiC5kVkud5PJAoZVBaKyAmP4puC
associationName[]: National Basketball Association
variety[]: 
volume[]: 
startDate[]: 
endDate[]:

Comment: Looks like your validation rules are working as expected, as they are submitted (`required`). Try and specify further what kind of content you expect.

Comment: I expect to display the error messages - e.g. 'Please select a commodity.', 'Please enter the variety.', etc. but 'Please select a commodity.' is the only error message that is showing.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you create an entire entry on say, `items` for each row you want to represent, this will make it easier - and group the data in the request that is sent.

Each form element's name should have a prefix of `items[]`, for example:

```html
<input name="items[][commodity]"/>
<input name="items[][variety]"/>
<input name="items[][volume]"/>
<!-- ... and the rest --!>
```

In your controller, you then simply do:

```php
foreach($request->input('items') as $item){
   ELinkage::create([
       'userId' => $user->id,
       ...Arr::only($item, ['commodity', 'variety', 'volume', /**Add the rest here...**/]),
   ];
}
```

For your rules (this is the important part, Laravel validates using `field.*.key` to scope it onto a wildcard(`*`) of array elements with its children columns.:

```php
return [
   'items.*.commodity' => 'required',
   'items.*.variety' => 'required',
   'items.*.volume' => 'required',
   //...
];
```

Comment: Hello! I appreciate your effort. Unfortunately, I am having this error - Undefined constant "index"

Comment: @ChristianTejano where do I or you define index? There is no "index" defined in the code provided by me, it is in your code and in a previous edit of the answer. The examples i wrote was changed before your comment.

Comment: Hello. The custom validation message is showing now but I can't submit the form because the validation message is still showing even if I filled up the fields.